# Hibernate seems print wrong sql bindings

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

The following code

```java
        final int size = 1;
        final var all = repositoryInstance().findAllByBirthDate(birthDate, Pageable.ofSize(size));
        log.debug("all({}): {}", all.getContent().size(), all.getContent());
        assertThat(all)
                .hasSizeLessThanOrEqualTo(size)     // passes
                .extracting(Employee::getBirthDate)
                .containsOnly(birthDate);
```

logs

```
17:05:25.175 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL -- 
    select
        e1_0.emp_no,
        e1_0.birth_date,
        e1_0.first_name,
        e1_0.gender,
        e1_0.hire_date,
        e1_0.last_name 
    from
        employees e1_0 
    where
        e1_0.birth_date=? 
    limit
        ?, ?
[main] TRACE org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind -- binding parameter (1:DATE) <- [1953-09-02]
[main] TRACE org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind -- binding parameter (2:INTEGER) <- [0]
[main] TRACE org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind -- binding parameter (3:INTEGER) <- [2]
```

When I execute the sql by myself,

```sql
select e1_0.emp_no,
       e1_0.birth_date,
       e1_0.first_name,
       e1_0.gender,
       e1_0.hire_date,
       e1_0.last_name
from employees e1_0
where e1_0.birth_date = '1953-09-02'
limit 0, 2
;
```

I got two rows.

```
10001, 1953-09-02, Georgi,  M, 1986-06-26, Facello
12138, 1953-09-02, Takahito,F, 1992-10-31, Brender
```

Funny thing is that the assertion passes and the log confirms.

```
all(1): [Employee(super=....Employee@2730, empNo=10001, birthDate=1953-09-02, firstName=Georgi, lastName=Facello, gender=M, hireDate=1986-06-26)]
```

Is this normal?